# In meta hydroxy benzaldehyde which position (w.r.t hydroxy group) is more prone to electrophilic attack?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In meta hydroxy benzaldehyde which position (w.r.t hydroxy group) is more prone to electrophilic attack ?

My approach:I considered hydroxy group as the stronger +M group.So my guess was para position w.r.t hydroxy group.But that's not the correct answer.

The answer is actually given as ortho w.r.t hydroxy and para w.r.t -CHO group!!

Comment: @yasir can you please explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the **ortho effect.** According to it if an **ortho/para** and **meta** directing group are **meta** to each other, then the incoming electrophile prefers to come on **ortho** of **meta** directing group.

See the **reference**.

[image]

Comment: I wanted t0 know for m-hydroxy benzaldehyde

Comment: The same applies for m-hydroxy benzaldehyde too.In this case, you have $\ce{Cl}$ which is ortho/para directing meta to $\ce{NO2}$ group which is meta directing.In your case, $\ce{OH}$ which is ortho/para directing is also meta to $\ce{CHO}$ group which is meta directing.

Comment: @yasir Please edit in the complete reference. Give credit where credit is due.

Comment: So are you saying that the OP's stated 'correct' answer is wrong?

Comment: @Bon That's what i have learnt from my text.I would like someone to kindly elaborate on  ortho effect as my knowledge of it is limited.